# Modal function not firing on radio button change after first selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, modal-dialog, onchange

So I have some radio buttons for shipping prices that are generated dynamically. I cannot change how it is generated but I can add code to change/add functionality, add styling, etc.

What I need to add, is a modal that only shows up when the user chooses the "No Shipping Charges" option. I currently have this working fine if the user initially chooses this option. However, if the user chooses one of the other options, say a truck option, and then changes their mind and chooses the "No Shipping Charges" option, the it doesn't cause the modal to fire in this case.

I've tried a multitude of different ways to call the change event, the click event, I've looked at a variety of stack overflow articles but can't seem to figure out why my code in particular isn't working.

Here is the HTML. I know that wrapping these in a table and using a span instead of a label isn't great practice but this is all dynamically generated and I don't have a lot of control over it:

```js
var dataSet = {
  "Code": ["Custom_01", "Custom_02", "Custom_03"],
  "Name": ["Truck - MD Area", "Truck - DC Area", "No Shipping Charge"]
}

var dataArray = new Array();
dataArray[0] = new Array("Custom_01", "OT1", "7", "1", "Truck - MD Area"); //Truck - MD Area
dataArray[1] = new Array("Custom_02", "OT2", "7", "2", "Truck - DC Area"); //Truck - DC Area
dataArray[2] = new Array("Custom_03", "U11", "1", "2", ""); // No Shipping Charge

$(function() {
  pmshipmethod();

  $("input[name='FIELD_38']").on('change', function(field) {
    if ($("input[value='Custom_03']").is(":checked")) {
      noShippingModal();
      pmshipmethod();
    } else {
      pmshipmethod();
    }
  });

});


function noShippingModal() {
  // Function that callls Modal to appear if user chooses "No Shipping"
  console.log("noShippingModal called");
}


function pmshipmethod() {
  // Code that sets freight information up for shipping
  console.log("pmshipmethod called");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" value="Custom_03" name="FIELD_38" checked>
        <span>No Shipping Charge</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" value="Custom_01" name="FIELD_38">
        <span>Truck Area 1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" value="Custom_02" name="FIELD_38">
        <span>Truck Area 2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I expect the noShippingModal() function to fire whether the user chooses the No Shipping Charges first or after choosing a different shipping option and then choosing the No Shipping Charges options.

Comment: I converted your posted code to a snippet, and it works as expected here. The problem may be due to the actual code in the functions.

Comment: Same experience here, it appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/q4s78ujo/ (hit f12 to view the console and see that it writes to console fine)

Comment: No, it's not writing to the console. It seems like it might be that there is an ajax call being made by the template system my company uses after a shipping option is selected, the ajax call seems to be updating shipping prices based on the selection and I think it might be what's causing the problem. 

So how would I then force this code to run after the ajax call was finished?